# Slug not being updated using wp_insert_post

Tags: php, functions

I am using this code to change the slug of a URL page every minute. However, nothing happens. I would presume the problem lies with post_name ?

```
function wpse402903_schedule_event() {

    add_action( 'wpse402903_cron', 'wpse402903_cron_callback' );
    
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled('wpse402903_cron') ) {
      
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 1 * 60, 'wpse402903_cron' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse402903_schedule_event' );

function wpse402903_cron_callback() {
    
    $post_id = 791;
    
    $postID = wp_insert_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => 'my-new-slug',
    ));
}
```

Comment: "However, nothing happens" - does the post title change but not the URL or nothing changes at all?

Comment: I don't see any changes either in the title nor the slug of the Page

Comment: Try moving the `add_action( 'wpse402903_cron', ...` out of the init hook, that might be too late. And recurrence should be a string, not `1*60`

Comment: i tried both suggestions, but it doesn't make any difference. The function doesn't work for me, irrespectively of the cron job..

Comment: Tried adding the function to add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');

Comment: I am dealing with a Page - not a post... would that make a difference ?

Answer (score -1):

```
wp_insert_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => 'my-new-slug',
    ), true);
```

Apparently wp_insert_post needs the true argument..

Comment: true at that position determines whether or not to return an error object, default is to return 0, has no effect on the main issue.